Putting span below the H3
Hi I'm trying to get the tan paragraphs below the h3's. Here is a photo of what it looks like currently:

Also want to make sure it stays in two rows as currently pictured. I tried multiple version of flex and display.


.details_container {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: lavender;  
}

.paragraph{
  background-color: tan;
}
<div class=details_container>  
    <div>
        <h3 class="bold_container">A Massive 1.5 Inch Touch Screen</h3> 
    </div>
        <div>
            <span class="paragraph">Size is what matters when it comes to a smart watch screen. Read all your notifications with plenty of space.</SPAN>
        </div>
    <div>
        <h3 class="bold_container">Mix and Match Designs</h3> 
    </div>
        <div>
            <span class="paragraph">Personalize your watch face to match your own unique style with many combinations of background images, clock styles and colors.</span>
        </div>
    <div>
        <H3 class="bold_container">Water Resistant up to 7 Feet</H3>
    </div> 
        <div> 
            <span class="paragraph">IP68 Weatherproof rating. Fit to withstand dust, dirt and sand and resistant to submersion up to a maximum depth of 7 feet underwater for up to 30 minutes.</span>
        </div>
</div>
<div Class="details_container">
    <div class="test2">
        <H3 class="bold_container">Tracking your Steps, Heart Rate & Sleep.</H3> 
    </div>
        <div>
            <span class="paragraph">Check out your step progress during the day with the in app-tracker. Keep an eye on your heart rate easily and conveniently. And when you’re ready for your head to hit the pillow, track that too. </span>
        </div>
    <div>
        <H3 class="bold_container">Notifications from Popular Apps</H3> 
    </div>
        <div>
            <span class="paragraph">Get all your notifications from all your accounts conveniently on your wrist</span>
        </div>
    <div>
        <H3 class="bold_container">Up to 10 Days of Battery Life</H3> 
    </div>
        <div>
            <span class="paragraph">With a battery capacity up to 300mAh, you’ll have no problem getting through the week with plenty of charge to spare.</span>
    </div>
</div>




Why are you wrapping everything with DIVs and using SPAN class="paragraph" instead of P? Also, check your nesting and matching of closing tags with opening tags.

Also, can you provide a mock-up of what you WANT it to look like?

All of those <div> elements in each .details_container element are side-by-side in the flex display.  It sounds like you want them to not be separate elements, but to combine the <h3> and the <span> under the same <div>.  For example:


.details_container {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: lavender;  
}

.paragraph {
  background-color: tan;
}
<div class="details_container">
  <div>
    <h3 class="bold_container">A Massive 1.5 Inch Touch Screen</h3> 
    <span class="paragraph">Size is what matters when it comes to a smart watch screen. Read all your notifications with plenty of space.</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3 class="bold_container">Mix and Match Designs</h3> 
    <span class="paragraph">Personalize your watch face to match your own unique style with many combinations of background images, clock styles and colors.</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3 class="bold_container">Water Resistant up to 7 Feet</h3>
    <span class="paragraph">IP68 Weatherproof rating. Fit to withstand dust, dirt and sand and resistant to submersion up to a maximum depth of 7 feet underwater for up to 30 minutes.</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="details_container">
  <div class="test2">
    <h3 class="bold_container">Tracking your Steps, Heart Rate & Sleep.</h3> 
    <span class="paragraph">Check out your step progress during the day with the in app-tracker. Keep an eye on your heart rate easily and conveniently. And when you’re ready for your head to hit the pillow, track that too. </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3 class="bold_container">Notifications from Popular Apps</h3>
    <span class="paragraph">Get all your notifications from all your accounts conveniently on your wrist</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3 class="bold_container">Up to 10 Days of Battery Life</h3> 
    <span class="paragraph">With a battery capacity up to 300mAh, you’ll have no problem getting through the week with plenty of charge to spare.</span>
  </div>
</div>




Yes I separated them too much. thanks exactly what I was trying to do

@zacharymiddleton, if this answer solves your problem, you may want to accept it as the answer using the big checkmark under the voting buttons for the answer. More information here.
